# How to out from looping without running the script below

Tags: loops, go, break

i want to out from second looping to first looping (like break) but after break i dont want to print `fmt.Println("The value of i is", i)`. How is the algorithm?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 4; j++ {
            if j == 2 {
                fmt.Println("Breaking out of loop")
                break
            } else {
                fmt.Println("j = ", j)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("The value of i is", i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** You edited you code, so here's the edited answer for that.

To continue the outer loop from the inner (breaking the inner loop and skipping the rest of the outer loop), you have to continue the outer loop.

To address the outer loop with the `continue` statement use a label:

```
outer:
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 4; j++ {
            if j == 2 {
                fmt.Println("Breaking out of loop")
                continue outer
            } else {
                fmt.Println("j = ", j)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("The value of i is", i)
    }
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mwwPuFu_Yvg)):

```
j =  0
j =  1
Breaking out of loop
j =  0
j =  1
Breaking out of loop
```

---

Original answer:

`break` always breaks from the innermost loop (more specifically a `for`, `switch` or `select`), so after that the outer loop will continue with its next iteration.

If you have nested loops and from an inner loop you want to break from the outer loop, you have to use labels:

```
outer:
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 4; j++ {
            if j == 2 {
                fmt.Println("Breaking out of loop")
                break outer
            }
            fmt.Println("The value of j is", j)
        }
    }
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kehYYtH-lQE)):

```
The value of j is 0
The value of j is 1
Breaking out of loop
```